# "Sometimes" duplicate call of controller method with identical timestamp / insert date

Tags: laravel

I'm facing an issue where a create is called twice and I cannot find out why. Per definition a `user` CAN have multiple `locations` but he should only create one. I also have a check in place for that. He will be `owner` and `user` of the `location`

The created entities have the exact same `created_at` date, but a different access_key (which is created randomly).

My first assumption would be that the UI is doing the call twice (due to internet lag and double clicking or something like that). However, I would like to prevent the duplicate creation backend wise.

I have a simple route definition for creation

```php
Route::post('/locations', 'LocationController@create');
```

And the corresponding controller method

```php
public function create (CreateLocationRequest $request) {
  if (Auth::user()->ownedLocations()->count() > 0) {
    return response()->json(Auth::user()->ownedLocations()->first(), 201);
  }

  $location = Auth::user()->ownedLocations()->make($request->validated());

  $access_key = rand(100000, 999999);

  while (Location::where('access_key', $access_key)->exists()) {
    $access_key = rand(100000, 999999);
  }

  $location->access_key = $access_key;
  $location->access_key_set_at = Carbon::now();

  $location->save();

  $location->users()->syncWithoutDetaching([Auth::user()->id]);

  return response()->json($location, 201);
}
```

For some reason - sometimes (not always) the call seems to run twice. I have two entities created in my DB - even though I have a check in place (first line) that should get the ownedlocation and return it in case there is already one existing.

Any Ideas?

Comment: "Per definition a user CAN have multiple locations but he should only create one. I also have a check in place for that. He will be owner and user of the location" This is a bit confusing, and worth drilling down on before proceeding. What are the other locations? Who creates them? Why can he have multiples, but only create one? Can he edit any of them?

Comment: It was originally planned he can have more than one - now it should be limited. But making the changes to the relations, db etc. would take too much time as the project is already live.
He can right now edit them etc. it's just not good it is created twice. Therefore I'm looking for a way to get rid of this behaviour. Making the column unique would be a way obiously - but then still an error would occur...

Comment: It's not the answer you are looking for, but the hard path of working to replace the relationship with a one-to-one, and investigating and resolving the UI calling twice is the best path through this. If the UI is firing two http requests close enough to each other, the second one could well be past the check you have in place before the first one has finished writing to the database. This is a difficult problem to solve here.

Comment: One thing that might help is to replace the method you use for generating the access_key to use a uuid in place of a random number. The method you have uses at least one database query, and potentially more. Resolving this should speed up execution, and reduce the chance the the first save isn't completed before the second starts.

Comment: Maybe you put to much weight in updating the relationships without changing the database, not knowing your database structure, but I have replaced a hasMany with hasOne and hasManyThrough with hasOneThrough without ever changing the table structure. I'm sure you can change belongsToMany with belongsTo also. I'd suggest you double check changing the relations without changing table structure before you dismiss it again.